# Virtual Audio Cable Crossovers?

Tags: windows-10, audio

Is there a way to crossover 2 different application's input/output?

Application 1's Output = Application 2's Input
Application 2's Output = Application 1's Input

I currently have VBAudio Cable installed, but it only works in 1 direction.

Visual of What I'm Trying to Do:

[image]

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Please add an OS tag. Under Linux, it's easy to do this with Pulseaudio and "dummy" audio sinks. (which is BTW not a product or service that needs recommendation @DavidPostill)

Comment: @dirkt As the question stands it is asking for software.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm not sure how else to word this.It's a pretty straight forward and simple question.

Comment: @K0D3R I've removed "Is there a software solution that can handle this?" from the question and reopened it.

Comment: Is there a virtual mixer your can use?

Comment: It depends on the applications. With your example and applications that support active configuration of the input and output device (or at least stick to a device after being started) the virtual audio cable is sufficient (you just need two). You'd  just configure them as a cross over. A lot of software doesn't support configuring the audio device to output to though. With those applications you're out of luck. With the exception of the ones that don't follow default device changes after they're being started.